# Stop zooming at a certain level in Bokeh WheelZoomTool

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to stop zooming in at a certain x axis level? I am using a `xwheel_zoom` tool in my dashboard with a `datetime` x-axis. This is the tick format I'm using:

```
p.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
            microseconds=["%H:%M:%S:%3Nms"],
            milliseconds=["%H:%M:%S:%3Nms"],
            seconds=["%H:%M:%S"],
            minsec=["%H:%M:%S"],
            minutes=["%H:%M:%S"],
            hourmin=["%H:%M:%S"],
            hours=["%H:%M:%S"],
            days = ['%m/%d', '%a%d'],
            months = ['%m/%Y', '%b %Y'],
            years = ['%Y']
            )
```

Is it possible to just stop the zooming in (like being deactivated when the user scrolls) when the datetime reaches a millisecond scale? My chart makes sense only up to seconds, and I don't want the user to be able to zoom in forever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zooming is not about formatters, it's about ranges. Try setting the [`min_interval` property](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d.min_interval):

```py
plot.x_range.min_interval = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```